# OFFSET function in Excel for Dynamic Table Named Range

Tags: excel, formula, offset

I am working with a dynamic data range, so whenever new columns or rows are added either as the last column / row OR anywhere within the data range it would update the records.
I created an OFFSET function for a dynamic data range:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A:$A,0,0,COUNTA(Data!$B:$B),COUNTA(Data!$1:$1))
```

But the issue is that it is updating new columns inside the existing columns.
I honestly have tried several other ways but without success.

Example table:
Column A      Column B     Column C

Need to Add Column D between Column A and Column B

Desired Output:

```
Column A     Column D   Column B     Column C
123             456       789          10 11
```

But I am getting:

```
Column A     Column B     Column C
123            789         10 11
456            789         10 11
456            789
456            456
123
123
```

Column D column has not been added but has just been updated in the cells within the Column A and B

Which is not what I am looking for

Comment: I am not understanding the problem clearly. can you reiterate what the problem is and be a little more specific as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your response. I have just added more explainations

Comment: That formula is not doing that.  How are you using the formula?

Comment: I created a Name manager and wrote the OFFSET formula inside

Comment: Okay cool, but how are you calling that name and using it in the sheet?  that is the point of the error not the name itself.

Comment: called in the VBA macro

Comment: please provide the relevant code.  Again the issue is there and not in the name or the formula.

Comment: good to know the formula is all good. kk